# Python Flask - Newly Added Templates Resulting in 404 while in Development (Debug) Mode

Tags: python, flask

I am following the Flask documentation tutorial here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/

I am currently at the "Templates" section (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/templates/) where after creating my Blueprint routes in the previous section, we create the html template files to render with `render_template`.

My project structure is this so far:

```
../flask-tutorial
├── flaskr/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── schema.sql
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── auth/
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   └── register.html
├── venv/
```

My `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    from . import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)

    return app
```

While this is my `auth.py` file:

```
import functools

from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from flaskr.db import get_db

bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')


@bp.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None

        if not username:
            error = 'Username is required.'
        elif not password:
            error = 'Password is required.'

        if error is None:
            try:
                db.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)",
                    (username, generate_password_hash(password)),
                )
                db.commit()
            except db.IntegrityError:
                error = f"User {username} is already registered."
            else:
                return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/register.html')


@bp.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone()

        if user is None:
            error = 'Incorrect username.'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Incorrect password.'

        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/login.html')


@bp.before_app_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    user_id = session.get('user_id')

    if user_id is None:
        g.user = None
    else:
        g.user = get_db().execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?', (user_id,)
        ).fetchone()


@bp.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


def login_required(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped_view(**kwargs):
        if g.user is None:
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

        return view(**kwargs)

    return wrapped_view
```

There are two things that I am stumped on:

1. When I navigate to the routes I defined in `auth.py` I receive a 404, even though the routes appear to be correct (e.g., `http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/register`). To be sure, when I run `flask routes` in Powershell, I can see they exist in the place I expect them to:

```
flask-tutorial> flask routes
Endpoint       Methods    Rule
-------------  ---------  -----------------------
auth.login     GET, POST  /auth/login
auth.logout    GET        /auth/logout
auth.register  GET, POST  /auth/register
hello          GET        /hello
static         GET        /static/<path:filename>
```

However, when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/register` (no trailing slash), I get a 404. The same occurs with all `/auth/..` paths.

2. Additionally, I noticed that even if I navigate to the base URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`, the function `hello` is run as if I visited `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello`. What is more odd is that once I visit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello`, I receive a different message of `Hello, hello!`.

I am on Windows, so before running my app I set the following environment variables:

```
$env:FLASK_APP = 'flaskr'
...
$env:FLASK_ENV = 'development'
```

I then start up the server with `flask run` where I receive the below response in my console:

```
flask-tutorial> flask run                     
 * Serving Flask app 'flaskr' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 124-376-921
```

From what I can tell, it seems a.) My changes aren't being detected, as I am receiving rendered results that do not match up with the functions I'm using to handle certain routes and b.) That my new templates aren't being received by the `render_template` function which is resulting in the 404 error.

Any help that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Adding for additional context - when I specify another port number like 3000 using `flask run -h localhost -p 3000`, I then see the updated contents. Here is the output from Powershell:

```
flask-tutorial> flask run -h localhost -p 3000
 * Serving Flask app 'flaskr' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://localhost:3000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 124-376-921
```

It's almost like specifying the additional arguments enables hot reloads whereas just `flask run` says they are enabled (with `Debug mode: on`), but appear not to be? Not sure why this would be the case.

Comment: Could you add the output from the commandline? So after the `flask run`

Comment: I also would put the `prefix` not inside the Constructor of the Blueprint. Add them to the `app.register_blueprint` call

Comment: Hi @Kevin, thanks for looking into this - the full output from the commandline is in the last code snippet of my post.

Comment: I've also moved the `prefix` declaration into the `app.register_blueprint` call like you suggested but the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my Proton Mail Bridge installation was listening on port 5000, but for some reason no error was thrown saying the port was already in use. So what I was seeing was a previous version of my code.

After uninstalling Proton Mail Bridge and restarting my computer, I can now run `flask run` and see my updates as they are made in development mode.